# DragSource is not found in react-dnd

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-dnd

I'm learning about drag and drop in react, but I keep getting this error (see image) that DragSource doesn't exist in react-dnd. I have installed react-dnd using "npm install react-dnd". I haven't seen any answer to this bug in my of the research I did.

[react-dnd package in node_modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9mKj.png)

[image]

Code below:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {DragSource} from 'react-dnd'

const itemSource = {
    beginDrag(props) {
        return props.item
    },
    endDrag(props, monitor, component) {
        return props.handleDrop(props.item.id)
    }
}

function collect(connect, monitor) {
    return {
        connectDragSource: connect.dragSource(),
        connectDragPreview: connect.dragPreview(),
        isDragging: monitor.isDragging()
    }
}

class Item extends Component {
    render() {
        
const { isDragging, connectDragSource, item } = this.props;
        return connectDragSource(
            <div className='item'>
                <span>{item.name}</span> 
            </div> 
        )
    }
}

export default DragSource('item', itemSource, collect)(Item)
```

Answer (score 3):

According to react-dnd [release v15.0.0](https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/releases/tag/v15.0.0)

> The Decorators API has been removed and fully replaced by the Hooks
> API

The Decorators API included DragSource and DropTarget.
They can be replaced by useDrag and useDrop hooks from react-dnd.